# error from sched_setaffinity () call when tid is a kernel thread

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, scheduling, fedora, scheduled-tasks

I make a call to kernel function sched_setaffinity() to try to lock a kernel thread with a CPU, but it always fails with errno 22 that says "Invalid argument". The machine runs Fedora 15, with kernel version 2.6.38.

This call is successful if a non-kernel tid is passed in. Is this a restriction by the kernel, or is there some tweaking that can make it working?

Comment: Please post the code you're using. What return value do you get? You said errno is 22, but errno is a userspace concept, in the kernel, calls such as sched_setaffinity return a negative value (e.g. -EINVAL).

Answer (score 2):

Any kernel thread that is bound to a specific CPU with `kthread_bind()` cannot have its affinity changed.  It should be possible for other kernel threads, though.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you zero the map before setting it and passing it to `sched_setaffinity`.

```
CPU_ZERO(&mask);
```